# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

```
           getVideo(){
    var jsonBody = {};
    jsonBody['activity'] = "videoUrls";
    var apiUrl = "apiurl/";
    this.postCall(jsonBody, apiUrl)
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.message == "ok") {
         this.showVideo=true
         this.videoList=data.data.videoslist
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.showVideo=false
        if (err.json().message == 'videos not found') {
          console.log("videos not found")
        } else {
          console.log("videos not found")
        }
      });
  }

  setVideo()
  {
    console.log("s")
    return this.videoList;
  }

Above is my service.ts file

     this.VideoService.getVideo();

        this.VideoService.setVideo().subscribe(
          item => {
            console.log(item)
          })
```

this is the code I have written in component.ts file

ERROR Occurs 
ERROR Type Error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

for sharing the data between two different components

Comment: In your setVideo it's returning list and you are finding subscribe function how it is possible man????

Answer (score 1):

Your setVideo function must return an observable.
You can do that using of operator.

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
return of(this.videoList);
```